# QTextEdit::extraSelections do not work well on Linux/X11 when QTextEdit with wrapped lines has explicitly set small font size

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have recently found a bug in Qt on **Linux** and reported it to https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-108149 Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 with Qt 5.15.2, 6.2.4 and 6.4, all with X11. I also tested it on Windows 10 and macOS 12.6 and Wayland and these seem to work fine.

Here is a minimal reproducible example. The program should highlight every occurrence of "abcd" in the text edit. However if I set the font size of the text edit to 12 points or smaller, the words in every second line are NOT highlighted. If I do not specify the font size or set font point size of 13 or greater, the highlighting works fine. The same problem seems to be with `QPlainTextEdit`.

I get this (every second row not highlighted):

[image]

This is what I would expect (all rows highlighted):

[image]

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextEdit>

void highlight(QTextEdit *textEdit)
{
    QList<QTextEdit::ExtraSelection> highlights;
    QString word = "abcd";
    QString text = textEdit->toPlainText();
    int pos = text.indexOf(word);

    while (pos != -1)
    {
        int endPos = pos + word.length();

        auto highlight = QTextEdit::ExtraSelection();
        highlight.cursor = QTextCursor(textEdit->document());
        highlight.cursor.setPosition(pos);
        highlight.cursor.setPosition(endPos, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
        highlight.format.setForeground(QApplication::palette().color(QPalette::Link));
        highlights.append(highlight);

        pos = text.indexOf(word, endPos);
    }

    textEdit->setExtraSelections(highlights);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextEdit w;

    // THE NEXT LINES!!!
    // If point size 12 or smaller is used, then every second
    // row in the text edit is not highlighted.
    // If commented out, then everything works fine.
    // If point size 13 or greater is used, then everything works fine.
    QFont f;
    f.setPointSize(12);
    w.setFont(f);

    w.setPlainText("abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd "
                   "abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd");
    highlight(&w);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Any ideas for any workaround until this bug gets officially fixed?

Comment: Do you know what part is causing the bug ? Is it the `indexOf()` or the `setExtraSelections()` ?

Comment: Neither. The bug is somehow mysteriously caused by setting the font size as I commented in the code.

Comment: Yes but the font size setting did work well. It is the highlighting function that seems to doesn't support small font sizes. For me, it is not the set font size that is buggy but the highlighting. I did not test it but my guess would be that it is `setExtraSelections()` that have the bug.

Comment: Yes, of course it is the extra selections which is faulty. But it somehow intereferes with the font size... I do not understand why and how. And I did not manage to find any workaround yet. In my case I wanted point size 12 but with extra selections.

Comment: Did you try to highlight before setting the font size ? To see if it reproduces the same issue.

Comment: Yes, still the same problem.